# using Python and Flask why am I getting an indentation erro when I uploead a csv file?

Tags: python, flask, postgresql-9.3

I want to upload a csv file, open it and then insert each row into my postgres database. here is the code:

```
@app.route("/uploadcsv", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def uploadcsv():
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'photo' in request.files:
        csvfile = open(request.form['myfile'], 'r')
        sql = Prospect(first_name=row[first_name], last_name=row[last_name], email = row[email], phone=row[phone], designation=row[designation], company=row[company], industry=row[industry], tag=row[tag], created_at=row[created_at]) 
            db.session.add(sql)
        db.session.commit()
        #flash("Photo saved.")
    return render_template('upload.html')
```

I am receiving an indentation error. The heroku logs say:

```
IndentationError: unexpected indent
2015-11-07T18:52:19.650383+00:00 app[web.1]:     sys.exit(run())
2015-11-07T18:52:19.623486+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker
2015-11-07T18:52:19.623487+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2015-11-07T18:52:19.623489+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2015-11-07T18:52:19.623490+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2015-11-07T18:52:19.623495+00:00 app[web.1]:     db.session.add(sql)
```

I have tried multiple different indentation attempts and none work. what am I doing wrong here? All help gratefully received. Thank you.

Comment: `db.sesion.add(sql)` is over-indented, nothing to do with CSV of Flask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
            db.session.add(sql)
```

That line  of code should not be indented.

Comment: it should be indented at same level as `db.session.commit()`

Comment: thank you. There are other problems too but I will work on them and then come back!